# How to put password in mysql database that you export using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I do that? Is it possible? If it's not possible in phpmyadmin then can you tell me some alternative to achieve the same thing (putting a password to the mysql database that is being exported for backup)?

Comment: which passwords? mysql database dump doesn't contain auth creditians as ms sql backup does.

Comment: it doesn't have that function?then what do I do so that the database that is exported is still protected?

Comment: "exported" database is a plain-text file contains just data and nothing about users' accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords and permissions are stored in the database named mysql.
If you need to copy passwords you can dump and restore that database, but it will likely cause you problems, you can line by line restore from the database for tables that contain specific info.